# In dbt, Why is my incremental model not registering as incremental and the compiled sql is not what I would expect?

Tags: data-modeling, dbt, incremental-build

My incremental model is not working, and I don't know why! Thank you in advance.

My intention is to only process records that are within 60 days of today to be materialized into a table that has many years worth of data. Since a record can change until it is older than 60 days, I need to reprocess all records younger than 60 days every day.

So I set up an incremental model like this
[image]

Which, compiled, looks like this (notice that the 60 day clause does not show up, and I don't know why )
[image]

When I run this model, there is no mention of a temp table being created
[image]

also no mention of a merge action for the Unique_key clause at the top of my model

Comment: hey pro tip including the actual text is always much appreciated over screenshots on HN. Here's a quick guide on how to do so.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 2):

In the dbt cloud development environment, `is_incremental()` always evaluates to `False`.  In dbt cloud production runs (and using the CLI), `is_incremental()` evaluates to `True` if the table already exists.

Comment: Whoa whoa... can you explain a bit about this. Is this a bug? 

I changed to  {% if not is_incremental() %} and now the compiled SQL does show the where clause... im very confused

Comment: It’s not a bug, it’s by design (although I don’t fully understand the design choice).

Answer (score 1):

### `is_incremental()` behavior

Have you run this model before? How are you running this model? I ask because `is_incremental()` will only be `true`, and therefore your extra WHERE clause  will only be included if certain criteria are met.

The [docs here](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/configuring-incremental-models#understanding-the-is_incremental-macro) say:

> The `is_incremental()` macro will return `True` if:
>
> 1. the destination table already exists in the database
> 2. dbt is *not* running in full-refresh mode
> 3. the running model is configured with `materialized='incremental'`

In this case, you're right that #2 & #3 are both `True`, but my guess is that #1 is `False`

To learn more about `is_incremental()` check out [the source code](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt/blob/9c58f3465bf9907a2b62942de548f80650cd6288/core/dbt/include/global_project/macros/etc/is_incremental.sql#L2-L13), which, IMHO, clearly lays out the logic.

### no `TEMP` table being created?

> When I run this model, there is no mention of a temp table being created

I do see a `create or replace transient table` statement, which is how dbt makes a temp table on Snowflake ([source code](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt/blob/9c58f3465bf9907a2b62942de548f80650cd6288/plugins/snowflake/dbt/include/snowflake/macros/adapters.sql#L19-L23))